# Issue in last modified date of FileProperty

Tags: fileinfo

i got some file from clients that's creation and access date was in 7-6-2013 but modified date like 20-10-1842
so can any one say how it possible!

plz note that i am using Robocopy for copy files from one location to another so it will not change creation and windows 7 Operating system
& access date of any file.[image: DateTime Property Issue]

When we are fetching property using DSO.dll(Dynamic Shared Object Dll - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224351) for this kind of files, it gives creation/modification/lastAccessDate as : '1899:12:30 12:00:00 AM'

Please note we are having C#.net window applications.

Is there any idea of range contain by DSO model ? why it gives dummy/Incorrect date like 1899 ?

Let us know if any one has any idea about same.

Comment: Please provide source and destination operating system types and versions.

Comment: Hi, we do not have information about source operating system..

Comment: For Destination OS,We have version-6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601, Microsoft Windows 7 enterprise

Comment: I think you've found the source of your issue.  You may well be copying files from a SAMBA share on some non-windows OS that has a defect and incorrectly reports file modification date/times.

Comment: Thanks for the information, also we are facing problem while getting correct date using DSO file, have edited my question for the same.